# Как сделать такую тень в .svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

Нужно сделать [такую](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2uewlmg9bd9udi/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-07-12%2012.08.42.png?dl=0) тень для .svg
Пока что получилось только [так](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtlzxy6gcfe5oe2/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-07-12%2012.09.22.png?dl=0)

[Кодпен с моей СВГ](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgoEaz)

```
                <svg height="240px" width="356px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <defs>
                    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
                        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"></feGaussianBlur>
                        <feOffset dx="-1" dy="1" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
                        <feMerge>
                            <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
                            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
                        </feMerge>
                    </filter>
                </defs>
                <image xlink:href="cards/card11.svg" x="0" y="0" fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#dropshadow)"></image>
            </svg>
```

Comment: для вас вопрос еще актуален? Если да, то обновите умершие ссылки, попробую ответить.